# Is it possible to connect 2 PLC which have Ethernet interfaces using Ethernet shield, arduino Nano and SX1278?

Tags: arduino-nano, ethernet

I need to connect 2 PLC which have Ethernet interfaces over 1 km and i was thinking of connecting via SPI an ethernet shield and an SX1278 module to a arduino nano (UNO) board.

Do i need logical converter between Nano and SX ? (I saw a lot of videos showing people doing it without the logical converter)

Is it Nano capable of handling the information passing from Ethernet to SX ?

If possible,  where can i find an example of such setup ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact you are asking this question means you don't have the skills or knowledge to comprehend what it is you are asking (I don't mean this in a nasty way, just that in having to ask it shows you lack some of the basic knowledge you will first need to accomplish the task).

Firstly you need to understand what Ethernet is.  The cable itself is just one layer (the "Physical" or lowest layer) of the 7-layer OSI model.

On top of that are 6 more layers at increasing levels of abstratcion.

You will need to understand *what* is being communicated between the two PLCs and at what layer of the OSI model it makes the most sense to create your bridge.

Do you do it at the application level, where you receive the data that is sent by a PLC and interpret it, then send that interpretation over the bridge to be reconstructed at the other and? Or do you do it at the socket layer where you capture the raw information and send that, or at the transport layer where you take the network data and forward that, or at the data layer where you take the ethernet electrical signals and pass that logical data to the other end to be replicated?

But then of course there is the other question: Is it actually Ethernet? Or is it some other protocol that just happens to use CAT5 (or similar) cables to transfer the data? If that is the case you first need to what that protocol is before you can even consider connecting anything to the wire.

Only once you have answered those questions can you go on to ask more about implementing your setup.  Things like:

- What hardware do I need to connect to the PLC
- What protocol do I need to implement
- What high level facilities would the Arduino need to provide for the connection to function

Etc. Lots of questions.

So:

- Is it actually Ethernet or some other protocol carried by CAT5 cables, such as RS-485 / RS-422
- Given the actual protocol, what interface do you need to get?
- If it is Ethernet, does it use IP or something else (IPX?)
- If it is IP does it use TCP or UDP for communication? Or both?
- If it is IP what controls the IP addresses? Will you need to implement a DHCP server, or hijack the IP address of the "remote" end of the bridge?
- Once you understand the protocols, is timing critical in your system? Does PLC A expect a response from PLC B within a finite defined time frame?
- Given how unreliable a wireless connection is, how will you handle dropped or corrupted packets?
- Does your chosen connection technology have enough bandwidth to transmit the data fast enough to prevent a backlog of data and lost information?

As you can see there is a *huge* amount of things to consider when designing this kind of thing.

If you have a list of 20 steps to go through to implement this, you are trying to start at maybe step 15 or 16. You need to rewind right back to step 1 and look at the absolute basics of what it is you are trying to do and what it is you are trying to do it to.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, the purpose of this system is acting as a relay, because these PLC's are in fact SENECA Z-GPRS3 GSM Loggers, but one of them is placed in an very bad GSM signal area, so the normal GSM operation is out of the question. The PLC have Ethernet RJ45 interface, protocol is TCP - application level - Web server on port 80 and IP's are fixed like 192.168.1.100 for PLC -A and 192.168.1.101 for PLC -B. Timing is not critical, given the fact that their modems are 2G-GPRS transmission speed cannot exceed 20-50kbps, and regarding the packets ... loss-retransmit.

Comment: In that case, your best bet is to have one Arduino pretend to be the remote PLC at each end of the link and capture raw bytes from whatever TCP socket the local PLC is sending to.